# Sum of a sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{11}n\left[\frac{1^2}{1+n}+\frac{2^2}{2+n}+\cdots+\frac{11^2}{11+n}\right]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, summation-method

The given sum is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{11}n\left[\frac{1^2}{1+n}+\frac{2^2}{2+n}+\cdots+\frac{11^2}{11+n}\right]$$

I tried simplyfing it as:

$$1^2\left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12}\right] + 2^2\left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{13}\right] +\cdots +11^2\left[\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{13}+\cdots+\frac{1}{22}\right]$$

Finding the sum of each diverging series seems too lengthy for a problem with obvious symmetries, so I don't think this method is correct.

Comment: It is unlikely you will get a good simplification. Is there a reason to expect one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} {nk^2 \over k+n}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} {nk^2 +kn^2 \over k+n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} {kn^2 \over k+n}\\&=
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} nk\right)-S
\end{align}$$

Thus, $$\begin{align}S&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^N nk\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N n\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^N k\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N n\right)^2\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left({N(N+1) \over 2}\right)^2.\end{align}$$

Comment: @algorhythm Just finding symmetries in the problem can help.  It also helps to get rid of denominator stuff where possible.

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Comment: @algorhythm no prob

Comment: how is $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sum_{k=1}^{N} {kn^2 \over k+n}$ equal to $S$?

Comment: @DS Swap indices

Comment: is that allowed?

Comment: @DS Relabel $n$ as $k$ and $k$ as $n$

Comment: (+1) oh yes, I was being stupid. It is still a sum over all pairs $(n,k)$.

Comment: @DS since both the sums go from 1 to N, it wouldn't matter if we swapped it since the variables mean the same thing. But if we change one term from k to n, we would have to swap the other term from n to k so that there is no loss in generality.